# Move metadata field in SilverStripe CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I am trying to move the default Metadata field in the SilverStripe CMS but I can't seem to do so successfully. This is what I have tried:

```
    $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Content.Main", "Metadata");
    $fields->insertBefore(new FormField('Metadata', 'Metadata'), 'Content');
```

But it does not work. I can remove this field but adding it back in where I want it to be is the challenge since it's not just an ordinary textfield or HTML field. With the above code, I get a new Metadata field inserted where I want it to be, but it isn't the right field type nor does it contain any of the existing metadata field elements.

Is there a way to move around such a field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `$fields->fieldByName('Root.Main.Metadata')` to retrieve the current Metadata field so that we can place it back in.

Try the following:

```
function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    if ($metadataField = $fields->fieldByName('Root.Main.Metadata')) {
        $fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Main', 'Metadata');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $metadataField, 'Content');
    }

    return $fields;
}
```